# Python: Urllib proxyhandler error

Tags: python, urllib

So I'm fairly new to using the urllib.request library and I'm trying to run a proxy through proxy handler, however I keep getting this error message

```
assert hasattr(proxies, 'keys'), "proxies must be a mapping"
AssertionError: proxies must be a mapping
```

My code is

```
import urllib.request

proxy = "https://107.170.206.225"
handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxy)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://youtube.com/')
```

I've tried looking through the documentation and it said to make sure to use the dictionary mapping protocol but I'm unsure of how to do that so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right [the documentation for ProxyHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler) says that *"`proxies` must be a dictionary mapping protocol names to URLs of proxies"*. And it must be read as *"`proxies` must be a dictionary that maps protocol names to URLs of proxies"*. In your case `proxies` should be defined as follows.

```
proxies = {'https': '107.170.206.225'}
handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
```